# How is it possible to use Futura font and the languages pack together?

Tags: fonts, languages

I have this paper that I need to write in English and russian and in Futura font so I wrote this:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex % or: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,spanish,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setmainfont{Futura Medium}[ItalicFont={Futura Medium Italic}]

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
this is english and  español and русский 

\end{document}
```

this definitely shows the Futura font if compiled with XelateX but dosent show the russian characters.

I'm on macOS Sierra, using Texshop in Mactex distribution.

Comment: Are you sure the Futura font on your machine supports Cyrillic? The one on mine doesn't.

Comment: Which operating system, and which TeX distribution, is installed on your system?

Comment: Incidentally, it's not necessaryt to load the `inputenc` package if the document is compiled via XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico Added those info to the question, sorry.

Comment: Do you use MacTeX or something different (that's the distribution)?

Comment: @TeXnician yes I use MacTex)

Comment: Many thanks for providing these additional pieces of information. AFAICT, neither the official Futura font family, which is distributed by Linotype, nor various Futura clones -- including the digitisation provided by the Neufville Digital font foundry, which is used on MacOS systems -- provide Cyrillic characters. However, according to the [Wikipedia entry]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)) for the Futura font face, there a Cyrillic adaptation of Futura was created for the 1980 Summer Olympics held in Moscow. I have no idea if this clone is available online somewhere.

Comment: @Mico thank you very much for the answer. I really appreciate the help

Comment: http://allfont.net/download/futura-normal/ thia is a Futura with cyrillic characters

Comment: @Herbert and how can I make it work with latex?)

Comment: Save the file in your font folder and then it should be available as `\setmainfont{Futura-Normal}` or use the full file name instead of the symbolic name.

Comment: Futura PT by ParaType (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/futura-book/) is more reliable than downloads from allfont.net; the latter are badly encoded and of questionable legality.